# R with ggplot2 horizontal line for average

Tags: r, ggplot2, average

I've my script which reads data from csv file. I'am calculating average but I would like to see average on graph as horizontal line.

```
avg = myData$Electricity.Costs
mean(avg)

ggplot(data = myData, 
       aes(x = Date, y = Electricity.Costs, 
           group = Budget.Plan.Monthly.Amount, colours = "Budget.Plan.Monthly.Amount")) + 
   geom_line() + 
   geom_point(aes(colour = Budget.Plan.Monthly.Amount))
```

Could you please give me some advice?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
ggplot(data = myData, 
   aes(x = Date, y = Electricity.Costs, 
       group = Budget.Plan.Monthly.Amount, colours = "Budget.Plan.Monthly.Amount")) + 
geom_line() + 
geom_point(aes(colour = Budget.Plan.Monthly.Amount))+
geom_hline(yintercept = mean(avg))
```

Comment: Thank you very much just I need to change yintercept = avg to yintercept = mean(avg). Working fine now :)